# Flutter emulator crashes on first run after firebase install

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've followed a tutorial that describes the process of installing `firebase_auth` on my flutter app using Android Studio on a Windows PC. After altering the code as per the google firebase instructions and hitting run, the app crashes with the following errors:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La5z7.png)

I've searched countless threads looking for a solution to this and it seems that no one has experienced this problem.

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of text.  Instead copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the configs to gradle?

```
dependencies {
  // Add the google services classpath
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
}
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```